# Asp.net core 6 Html.DropDownListFor System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two classes "Customer" and "Deals" the customer has a foreign key relationship to the deal. The user should choose from the dropdown list the customer that makes the deal. So I create a ViewModel class that contains a SelectListItem of customers and a deal and update the creat in the deal controller, the error appears when creating the deals:

> System.NullReferenceException  HResult=0x80004003   Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

-**ViewModel**:

```
        public class CreateDealVM
    {
        public Deals deal { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedCustomer { get; set; }
        public int selectedCustomerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- **The DealController methods**

  ```
  public IActionResult Create()
   {
       Deals deal = new Deals();
       List<Customer> customerList = _context.Customers.ToList();
       CreateDealVM vm = new CreateDealVM();
       vm.selectedCustomer = new SelectList(customerList, "customerId", "customerName");
       vm.deal = deal;
       return View(vm);
   }


   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Create(CreateDealVM vm)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           try
           {

               vm.deal.customer =_context.Customers.Find(vm.selectedCustomerId); 
               _context.Deals.Add(vm.deal);
               _context.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Index");

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
           }
           return View(vm);
       }
       return View();
   }
  ```

**Deal Model class:**

```
   namespace MyShop.Models
{
    [Table("Deals")]
    public class Deals
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int dealId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        [Display(Name = "Customer")]
        public Customer customer { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CustomerName")]
        public string? parentCustomerName { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "product")]
        public DealTypeEnum product { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime saleDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        public float quantity { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public float price { get; set; }
    }
```

**The view.cshtml page** :

```
 @model MyShop.ViewModels.CreateDealVM

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Deals</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedCustomer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCustomerId, Model.selectedCustomer,"--Select--" )                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="deal.product" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="deal.product" class="form-control"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="deal.product" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="deal.saleDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="deal.saleDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="deal.saleDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="deal.quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="deal.quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="deal.quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="deal.price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="deal.price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="deal.price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I tried this link  [ASP.NET MVC DropdownlistFor Object reference not set to an instance of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247535/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object) but it did not work.

Comment: Did you check in debugger what a line of the code generates the `System.NullReferenceException` exception?

Comment: yeah , this line :                                                         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCustomerId, Model.selectedCustomer,"--Select--" )

Comment: Seems like you have not proper data model definition. Show more code of the `create.cshtml` view, please. Perhaps do you have loop in the `create.cshtml`?

Comment: I have updated the code above @Victor

Comment: Your code is working for me: [pic](https://i.imgur.com/mMsyEfu.png). Try to check the data model in the debugger or consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have this problem not when you render the `Create.cshtml` view the first time, but after you press <kbd>Create</kbd> button and the `ModelState.IsValid` in the `public ActionResult Create(CreateDealVM vm)` is `false`.

After that you just render the `Create.cshtml` view by calling

```
return View();
```

This is why the `Model` is  `null` when you trying to render the `Create.cshtml` view the second time.

You should use debugger to check this and if this is exactly what's happening  replace `return View();` line by

```
return View(vm);
```

In additional analyze your code in the view, to find out why the data model become not valid when passed from view to controller.